# Volume /mass / density problem

Tags: volume

If I have a solution that has a volume of 32.5mL, a mass of 40.0g, and a density of 1.23 --- how do I solve for 10mL, 15, 20mL, etc of the same solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "solve for", but if you want to find the mass of different volumes just remember that the density remains constant and use $m = \rho v$ where $\rho$ is density, $m$ mass and $v$ volume. Put in different values of $v$ to get different values of $m$ and use a spreadsheet if you're dealing with a lot of numbers.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, that explains it perfectly. I forgot that the density does not change!